Find Set of equivalence classes for relation $A R B \Longleftrightarrow A \triangle B \subseteq U$, and cardinality for that set.

For sets $\emptyset \ne U$, $U \subseteq X$, there is a relation $R \subseteq \mathcal{P} (X) \times \mathcal{P} (X)$ such that: $A R B \Longleftrightarrow A \triangle B \subseteq U$ ("$\triangle$" denotes the symmetric difference of sets, $\mathcal{P} (X)$ - Power set)
a) Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.
b) Determine $\mathcal{P} (X) / R$ and $|\mathcal{P} (X) / R|$.

I have problem with b). I don't know how to find equivalence classes for relation $A R B = A \triangle B \subseteq U$. From definition of equivalence class:

For any $A \in \mathcal{P} (X)$, its equivalence class $[A]_R$ is defined as: $[A]_R = \{ B \in \mathcal{P} (X) : A R B \}$

I can tell we need to consider $X \backslash U$, but I am stuck here.

How did you prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation? That should give you some hints, I think.

It helps to start by showing $R$ is an equivalence relation. Then you will get an intuition about what the equivalence classes look like.
To show that $R$ is an equivalence relation:

Reflexivity: Trivial. For any $A$, $A \triangle A = \emptyset \subseteq U$.
Symmetry: Trivial. For any $A, B$, we have $A \triangle B = B \triangle A$.
Transitivity: Assume $A \triangle B, B \triangle C \subseteq U$. Let $x \in A \triangle C$; by definition, either $x \in A - C$ or $x \in C - A$. If $x \in A - C$, then $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$. Suppose $x \in B$. Then $x \in B - C \implies x \in B \triangle C \implies x \in U$. Now suppose $x \notin B$. Then $x \in A - B \implies x \in A \triangle B \implies x \in U$. Either way, $x \in U$. A similar argument applies if $x \in C - A$. Therefore, $A \triangle C \subseteq U$.

From this, it is relatively easy to see that two sets $A, B$ are equivalent under $R$ exactly when $A$ and $B$ "agree" (i.e., contain the same elements) outside of the set $U$; that is, when $A - U = B - U$. This is easy to show.* With regards to (b) then, assuming $X$ is finite, the number of equivalence classes is simply $\boxed{2^{|X - U|}}$, because the classes are distinguished by the identity of elements outside of $U$.
* Suppose $A - U = B - U$. Let $x \in A \triangle B$; we want to show that $x \in U$. Suppose not. If $x \in A$, then $x \in A - U \implies x \in B - U \implies x \in A \cap B$, which contradicts $x \in A \triangle B$. Similarly, if $x \notin A$, then
$$A - U = B - U \Longleftrightarrow (X - A) \cup U = (X - B) \cup U$$
implies that $x \notin B$, which again contradicts $x \in A \triangle B$.
Now suppose $A \triangle B \subseteq U$. Let $x \in A - U$. Clearly $x \in B$, for if not, then $x \in A - B \implies x \in A \triangle B \implies x \in U$, a contradiction. Then because $x \notin U$ by hypothesis, $x \in B - U$. Similarly, if $x \in B - U$, then $x \in A$, for if not, then $x \in B - A \implies x \in A \triangle B \implies x \in U$, a contradiction. Then we have $x \in A - U$.

Thank you very much, that's what i wanted to know.
